Ceiling had new drywall installed now ceiling fixtures aren't working
I had my basement re-drywalled recently (the old drywall got damaged) and that included parts of the ceiling. While doing this the drywall installers took down two light fixtures that were in the 'living room' area of the basement and left them down. I was going to install new fixtures but was having trouble so called my dad to help. He brought a tool to verify power in the fixture and there is none. We checked wall sockets in the area to make sure the tool was working and it is fine, the power in my new office is fine, and no breakers in the house were tripped. He checked the light switch connected to those fixtures and it is not reading as powered either. Is this something that was caused by the drywall installers? Could they have knocked something loose? Should I call the company and tell them this is a problem now? I feel guilty potentially costing that company money by having to come back and deal with this.

Light fixtures are usually two simple connections to remove and re-attach.  Power is usually in the ceiling at the fixture or comes from the switch.  I would hope the installers did turn off the breaker for safety, so a slim possibility the breaker is broken/won't turn on(it happens).  Without knowing the circuit path, the problem might just be a bad/loose connection somewhere.

check ALL the GFCI outlets in the house.  The lights should not be on a GFCI but they could be wired to one. Check the garage as well.  Also check the breakers. Opened breakers may not looked tripped but they can be.  Finally if those checks produce nothing, there is the possibility the drywallers hit a wire while doing their work.

Troubleshooting this sort of thing usually takes either luck or experience. While I’m a fan of diy, I’d suggest you ask the drywallers to send a licensed electrician… if it turns out to be their fault (ie, they put a screw through a wire) then they pay; otherwise you pay.
